# Is it possible to place widgets off window?

Tags: python, tkinter

My question is simple - is it possible to place widgets out of bounds?
For example, I want a button to be not on `tkinter.Tk`, but it will be somewhere else like in the center of monitor.

Comment: You can just put the button in another toplevel window without border and then put that window in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter.Tk` are only can place within bounds of a parent widget. For this you can need to create transparent `tkinter.Toplevel`, then place in the needed location using method called `geometry`.

```
import tkinter as tk

source = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel(source)
top.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
width = source.winfo_screenwidth()
height = source.winfo_screenheight()
buttonsize = 50  
x = (width - buttonsize) // 2 
y = (height - buttonsize) // 2  
top.geometry(f"{buttonsize}x{buttonsize}+{x}+{y}")
button = tk.Button(top, text="Click me!")
button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

source.mainloop()
```

Comment: Window is empty and there is no button for some reason.

Comment: think so the button is invisible without the color you can add this line. `button = tk.Button(top, text="Click me!", bg='red')
`

Comment: Note that setting `alpha` to 0.0 will make the *whole window* invisible including widgets inside the window.

Comment: I still have the same issue. There is nothing except an empty window.

Comment: Ok I played around with it and found out that the ```-alpha``` should be ```1```. You just add ```top.overrideredirect(True)``` after you declare ```top```.
This leaves you with a default empty window and a button in the middle. Now, to hide the ```source``` you have to write ```source.attributes('-alpha', 0)``` and it hides the main window.

Comment: Then why don't you just use `source` in the first place and so you don't need to create `top`.